# Ошибка скрипта в unity RoomInfo.cs(16,13):The type or namespace name `bl_Lobby' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: unity3d

Помогите исправить ошибку unity 
Assets/MFPS/Scripts/UI/bl_RoomInfo.cs(16,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `bl_Lobby' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

вот код скрипта RoomInfo.cs

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class bl_RomInfo : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Text RoomNameText = null;
public Text MapNameText = null;
public Text PlayersText = null;
public Text GameModeText = null;
public Text PingText = null;
[SerializeField] private Text MaxKillText;
public GameObject JoinButton = null;
public GameObject FullText = null;
[SerializeField] private GameObject PrivateUI;
private RoomInfo cacheInfo = null;
private bl_Lobby Lobby;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="info"></param>
public void GetInfo(RoomInfo info)
{
    Lobby = FindObjectOfType<bl_Lobby>();
    cacheInfo = info;
    RoomNameText.text = info.Name;
    MapNameText.text = (string)info.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.CustomSceneName];
    GameModeText.text = (string)info.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.GameModeKey];
    PlayersText.text = info.PlayerCount + "/" + info.MaxPlayers;
    MaxKillText.text = string.Format("{0} Kills", (int)info.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.RoomMaxKills]);
    PingText.text = ((int)info.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.MaxPing]).ToString() + " ms";
    bool _active = (info.PlayerCount < info.MaxPlayers) ? true : false;
    PrivateUI.SetActive((string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)cacheInfo.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.RoomPassworld]) == false));
    JoinButton.SetActive(_active);
    FullText.SetActive(!_active);
}
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public void JoinRoom()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.GetPing() < (int)cacheInfo.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.MaxPing])
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)cacheInfo.CustomProperties[PropertiesKeys.RoomPassworld]))
        {
            Lobby.FadeImage.SetActive(true);
            Lobby.FadeImage.GetComponent<Animator>().speed = 2;
            if (cacheInfo.PlayerCount < cacheInfo.MaxPlayers)
            {
                PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(cacheInfo.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FindObjectOfType<bl_Lobby>().CheckRoomPassword(cacheInfo);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Lobby.MaxPingMessageUI.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Оно говорит вам, что у вас не существует класса `bl_Lobby`, который вы используете для объявления переменной `Lobby`. Видимо, у вас опечатка в названии класса

Comment: а как решить что написать ?

Comment: @Dimooooooon, класс "bl_Lobby" написан Вами? Если да, то, возможно, не указано использование пространства имен для этого класса. Либо Вы что-то напутали и такого класса/типа данных просто не существует в Вашем проекте.